# A small doubt in reciprocal space (aka $k$-space) in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

In the Sommerfeld theory of free electron gas, it was mentioned in Griffiths that the electrons will fill up one octant of a sphere in $k$-space.

I pondered upon this for a while but couldn't convince myself. Please explain.
Also what about the other 7/8th portion of the sphere..Is it just unoccupied by electrons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also what about the other 7/8th portion of the sphere..Is it just
> unoccupied by electrons?

Looking at an older version of Griffiths' QM online, on page 232 and page 233 he is treating a free electron in a three dimensional box. In this case he applies boundary conditions such that the wave function is zero on the sides of the box. Therefore (similar to one-dimensional particle in a box) solutions look like
$$
\sin(n_x \pi x/L)\sin(n_y \pi y/L)\sin(n_z \pi z/L)
$$
where $n_x$=1,2,3,4,... and $n_y$=1,2,3,4,... and $n_z$=1,2,3,4,...

You will notice that $n_x$, $n_y$, and $n_z$ do not take on negative values. They only take on positive values. I.e., the vector $\vec n$ takes on values in the first octant. The vector $\vec k$ defined as $\pi\vec n/L$ thus takes on values in the first octant.

The free electron wave functions are used as the basis for the free electron gas theory.